# Array of a generic class with unspecified type

Tags: c#, generics, typing

Is it possible in C# to create an array of unspecified generic types? Something along the lines of this:

```
ShaderParam<>[] params = new ShaderParam<>[5];
params[0] = new ShaderParam<float>();
```

Or is this simply not possible due to C#'s strong typing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not possible. In the case where the generic type is under your control, you can create a non-generic base type, e.g.

```
ShaderParam[] params = new ShaderParam[5]; // Note no generics
params[0] = new ShaderParam<float>(); // If ShaderParam<T> extends ShaderParam
```

My guess is that this is an XNA type you have no control over though.

Comment: It's not, it's my own class ;). Trying it now.

Answer (score 12):

You *could* use a covariant interface for `ShaderParam<T>`:

```
interface IShaderParam<out T> { ... }
class ShaderParam<T> : IShaderParam<T> { ... }
```

Usage:

```
IShaderParam<object>[] parameters = new IShaderParam<object>[5];
parameters[0] = new ShaderParam<string>(); // <- note the string!
```

**But** you can't use it with value types like `float` in *your* example. Covariance is only valid with reference types (like `string` in *my* example). You also **can't use** it if the type parameter appears in contravariant positions, e.g. as method parameters. Still, it might be good to know about this technique.

Answer (score 4):

Rather late to the game, but here's how: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1097830/Down-the-Rabbit-Hole-with-Array-of-Generics

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't make sense.

What would happen if you write `params[3]`?
What type would it be?

You may want to create a non-generic base class or interface and use an array of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in a **generic class** or a **generic extension method** where T is defined:

```
ShaderParam<T>[] params = new ShaderParam<T>[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the concept `ShaderParam<>` is meaningless as far as an instantiated type is concerned.  In other words, a concrete `ShaderParam<float>` is *not* an instance of `ShaderParam<>`.  Therefore, the declared type of the array would be illegal for holding that instance.  (Above and beyond the fact that it's already illegal syntax to begin with.)

Answer (score 1):

create an array of unspecified generic types:

```
Object[] ArrayOfObjects = new Object[5];
ArrayOfObjects[0] = 1.1;
ArrayOfObjects[1] = "Hello,I am an Object";
ArrayOfObjects[2] = new DateTime(1000000);

System.Console.WriteLine(ArrayOfObjects[0]);
System.Console.WriteLine(ArrayOfObjects[1]);
System.Console.WriteLine(ArrayOfObjects[2]);
```

If you need to perform some type specific actions on the object you could use Reflection

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. A closed generic is a specific "type" behind the scenes, so even an open generic is too general to be a "strong type".

The best solution I can think of, which I've used before, is to create a non-generic ancestor to the generic class. Whether that solution will function depends on what you plan to use the array for.