# Array of inherited from generic types

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Code to demonstrate the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    Base<>[] all = new Base<>[] { a, b }; // doesn't work
}

class Base<T>
{
    public string Caption { get { return typeof(T).ToString(); } }
}

class A : Base<A> { }
class B : Base<B> { }
```

Perhaps I went the wrong direction. Idea was to move `Caption` into base class (`Base` become generic). Non-generic version works without problems:

```
var all = new Base[] { a, b }; // no problems for as long as Base is not generic
```

Comment: what do you expect? They should implement the same interface or base class for that to work, but .NET/CLR/C# doesn't have that. Generics create a new type at runtime.

Comment: Give the generic class a non-generic base class and create an array of that type.

Comment: @DanielA.White No, that's a common misconception. Unlike Java, C# generics are first-class citizens - that is why this is impossible, in fact. There's no common `Base<>` type that can hold both `Base<A>` and `Base<B>`. The only place where you can use `Base<>` is in `typeof(Base<>)` as far as I know. The type of the *concrete* generic class *must* be known at compile-time (excluding reflection, of course).

Comment: I'd expect to get `Caption` from `all`, but have no idea how. It should be either very easy or completely impossible. And if the later is the case, then I'd like to see a solution to my problem - moving `Caption` which is resolved *per type* into a base class somehow.

Comment: @Sinatr removed ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `Type<?>` in C# - you *always* have to specify a concrete generic type.

The only way around this is to make `Base<T>` inherit a non-generic base-class, or implement a non-generic interface. You could then use that as the type of the array.

**EDIT:**

In your case this is extremely simple, since the part of the interface you want doesn't include the generic type argument. So you can simply do either:

```
public abstract class Superbase
{
  public abstract string Caption { get; }
}

public class Base<T>: Superbase
{
  public override string Caption { get { return typeof(T).Name; } }
}
```

Or, using an interface:

```
public interface IBase
{
  string Caption { get; }
}

public class Base<T>: IBase
{
  public string Caption { get { return typeof(T).Name; } }
}
```

Your array would then be `Superbase[]` or `IBase[]`, respectivelly. In both cases, you can see that I'm not actually providing *an implementation* - both the declarations are "abstract", in a sense.

In general, I'm trying to keep the non-generic stuff in a non-generic base class, rather than stuffing it in the derived generic classes. It just feels more clean :)

Comment: Earlier I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5222828/1997232), but it doesn't helped me much. Can you should how exactly would non-generic base-class looks like to have `Caption` accessible? I know my code doesn't works, but in current form answer is not helpful to me.

Comment: *Interface* solution makes me feel very dumb. Like really dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

based on @Luaan ideea, here is an implementation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();

        var arr = new Base[] { a, b};

        foreach (var obj in arr)
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Caption);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Base<T> : Base
{
    public override string Caption
    {
        get { return typeof (T).ToString(); }
    }
}

public class A : Base<A> { }

public class B : Base<B> { }

public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract string Caption { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use inheritance (which will lead to more problems down the line), use an extension method instead:

```
public interface IClassAORClassB {}

class A : IClassAORClassB { }
class B : IClassAORClassB { }

public static class Captions
{
    public static string Caption<T>(this T obj) where T : IClassAORClassB
    {
        return obj.GetType().ToString();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    var all = new IClassAORClassB[] { a, b }; // works just fine
    Console.WriteLine(all[0].Caption()); // prints A
    Console.WriteLine(all[1].Caption()); // prints B
}
```

Comment: Actually, while I considered using an extension method, it doesn't help in this case - not if you want to use it on elements of `all`. It uses the compile-time type of the local, not the runtime, which isn't appropriate here. Not to mention that the OP wanted one specific type argument, not the type of the inherited class.

Comment: @Luaan, are you saying that `typeof(T).ToString()` will always return `IClassAORClassB`?

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks, but as @Luaan commented, `all[0].Caption()` will not do what is expected. Or will it?

Comment: It will return `IClassAORClassB` for `all[a]` and `all[b]`, `A` for `a` and `B` for `b`. Useful, but not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Luaan, you are correct. I've amended the code to use `obj.GetType()` instead of `typeof`. It now works correctly.

Comment: @Sinatr, it will now :)