# How do I correctly instance a generic class from field type and put it in an array

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create an instance of the `MonobehaviourField<T>` class and put it in the `monobehaviourFields` array. I want to use the type from the current field from `monobehaviourFields` as `T`. This line

```
monobehaviourFields[i] = new MonobehaviourField<typeof(fieldType)>("test");
```

isn't working. How can I make an instance based on the fieldType and put it in the array?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;

[Serializable]
public class MonobehaviourWrapper
{
    private MonobehaviourField<object>[] monobehaviourFields;

    public MonobehaviourWrapper(FieldInfo[] fields)
    {
        monobehaviourFields = new MonobehaviourField<object>[fields.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < monobehaviourFields.Length; i++)
        {
            Type fieldType = fields[i].FieldType;
            monobehaviourFields[i] = new MonobehaviourField<typeof(fieldType)>("test");
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MonobehaviourField<T>
    {
        [SerializeField] private string fieldName;
        [SerializeField] private T objectContainer;
        [SerializeField] private string typeName;

        public MonobehaviourField(string fieldName)
        {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.typeName = typeof(T).FullName;
        }

        public Type FieldType { get { return Type.GetType(typeName); } }
        public T ObjectContainer { get { return objectContainer; } set { objectContainer = value; } }
        public string FieldName { get { return fieldName; } set { fieldName = value; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but you will need to change your code a bit.

1. You cannot have an `MonobehaviourField<object>[]` and add, say a `MonobehaviourField<string>` to the array: `MonoBehaviourField` is not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). I have declared a non-generic base class, `MonobehaviourFieldBase` to get around this. See, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5222828/1364007) which had a similar issue.
2. You need to construct the generic class to make an instance of it, then use reflection to call the constructor. Here I use [MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype) to get from `MonobehaviourField<>` (note that there are **no** type parameters specified) to create a `MonobehaviourField<T>` where T is `fieldType`. I then use [`Type.GetConstructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getconstructor) to get the relevant constructor, and [`ConstructorInfo.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.constructorinfo.invoke) to actually call the constructor. Note that `Invoke` returns an instance of type `Object` so it needs to be casted to the interface to be added to the array.

Here is the code (note that for brevity I've removed the parts of your code which aren't part of your problem):

```
public class MonobehaviourWrapper
{
    private MonobehaviourFieldBase[] monobehaviourFields;

    public MonobehaviourWrapper(FieldInfo[] fields)
    {
        monobehaviourFields = new MonobehaviourFieldBase[fields.Length];

        for ( int i = 0; i < monobehaviourFields.Length; i++ )
        {
            Type fieldType = fields[i].FieldType;
            var constructedGenericType = typeof(MonobehaviourField<>).MakeGenericType(fieldType);
            var constructor = constructedGenericType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });

            object resultOfConstructor = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { "This code has worked" });
            monobehaviourFields[i] = (MonobehaviourFieldBase)resultOfConstructor;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MonobehaviourFieldBase> MonobehaviourFields
    {
        get
        {
            return monobehaviourFields;
        }
    }

    public class MonobehaviourField<T> : MonobehaviourFieldBase
    {
        public MonobehaviourField(string name)
        {
            FieldName = name;
        }
    }
}
```

and the base class:

```
public class MonobehaviourFieldBase
{
    private string fieldName;

    public string FieldName
    {
        get
        {
            return fieldName;
        }
        set
        {
            fieldName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Here is a working example of the code above](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xD0Yc8).

Comment: var constructedGenericType = typeof(MonobehaviourField<>).MakeGenericType(fieldType); is equal to null?

Comment: Just tried it with this class and it doesn't work, constructor is null `public class Tester
{
    public float floatField;

    public Tester()
    {
    }
}`

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure why `MakeGenericType` should return null. I can see why `GetConstructor` would return null: I made an obvious typo - the type passed in should always be `typeof(string)`, not `fieldType` because the constructor takes a string. That's now fixed in my answer.

Comment: My use of an interface fails when the field type is a struct because you can't use covariance with structs this way (e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28095804/1364007)), so I've gone with a base class, `MonobehaviourFieldBase`, instead. The updated sample has a `string` (class) field and a `float` (struct) field and works for both.